# How can I display a variable in an exponential format with 2 decimals in javascript?

Tags: javascript, format, decimal

I am trying to get the right format for my operations, I want an exponential but I would like to limit the number of displayed decimals to only 2, like for example 1.13E+2 how can I do this work? Thanks in advance

```
row.querySelector(".one").value = (C1 * fuel).toExponential();
row.querySelector(".two").value = (C2 * fuel).toExponential();
row.querySelector(".three").value = (C3 * fuel).toExponential();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use toFixed, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

```
row.querySelector(".one").value = Number.parseFloat((C1 * fuel).toExponential(2));
```

Comment: .toExponential(2) does the job